# Inject lines to bash history

Tags: bash

By default bash loads lines from `~/.bash_history` to history. Is it possible to add custom file to be also loaded? I want to inject file containing commands I frequently use and access them it via built-in search.

Comment: Typically people add aliases for frequently used commands...

Comment: That's great. But that's not the case - I use aliases for commands I use constantly but I have a lots of commands that have big number of arguments that I want to modify based on circumstances.

Comment: You would have to cron out some kind of file modification, which sounds rather crazy and may not work. Just make your long commands a shell script that accepts arguments and drop it in `/usr/local/bin` or something

Comment: If you use them frequently, wouldn't they be in your history anyway?

Comment: Declare functions in `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 13):

I keep it simple with an `alias h='history|grep'` loaded into my Bash profile.

So my workflow is `h command`, for example: `h hpssa`

```
#  h hpssa
  202  05-28-2015 11:54:33  hpssacli
  217  05-28-2015 11:54:33  hpssa -start
  225  05-28-2015 11:54:33  hpssacli -stop
  226  05-28-2015 11:54:33  hpssa -stop
  228  05-28-2015 11:54:33  hpssa -start
```

If I want to run "`hpssa -stop`",  I'd simply type `!226`

---

This is just my approach, but maybe you could modify how you're recalling history items. I don't think it makes sense to actually inject data into the history file.

Comment: nice trick, stealing that one

Comment: Suggest you may want to have a look at what Ctrl-R does for searching back  in your history. Prepare to have your mind blown...

Comment: @CameronKerr Have a look at the answer just below this one (http://serverfault.com/a/695115/120438 ).The downside to using Ctrl+R in this particular case is that it gives you the relevant commands one at a time, while ewwhite's approach returns a list of all relevant commands.

Comment: Although this is a great trick, it doesn't answer the question at all. I fail to understand as to how this is the highest voted answer. My usecase is that I have a docker image which keeps losing it's history when I exit it. I thought it'd be nice if I could pass a history file via the command line to `docker run ...`

Comment: @kumar_harsh Hard to please.

Answer (score 7):

I used to be very reliant on `Ctrl-R` (`reverse-search-history` Readline command) which searches backward through the history to retrieve previously entered long commands but I now prefer to use aliases and shell scripts / functions. Anyhow, the Bash `history` builtin command can be used to load a list of custom commands into your current history.

```
history -r [filename]
```

From the bash man page:

> Read the contents of the history file and append them to the current history list.

#### Start-up automation

I just tried launching this command automatically by adding it as the last line in my `.bashrc`. However, the commands from my custom history file were not available when I started a new shell. It seems that the shell history is only loaded from the default `.bash_history` file: *after* the start-up files have been processed and just *before* the prompt is presented for the interactive shell. Unfortunately, it seems there isn't an easy way to automate this.

Answer (score 2):

As @AnthonyGeoghegan observed, the history is loaded after startup files are processed.  That offers a different way to pre-load the desired history in a startup file:

```
mv .bash_history .bash_history.tmp
cat .extra_hist .bash_history.tmp > .bash_history
# or swap them, to put the extra stuff at the end of the history, for
# quicker ^R access.
```

Note that this approach could result in multiple copies of your special commands being added to your .bash_history, over time.  You could wrap your special commands with comment lines, so you can easily find and remove them (via, e.g., sed) as part of filling the .bash_history file.  Something like:

```
cp .extra_hist .bash_history
sed '/: remove from here/,/:remove to here/d' .bash_history >> .bash_history
```